Unable to initialize JavaScript cache storage
I am getting the following warning when building an angular project. Below is the configuration.
Angular CLI: 18.2.12
Node: 20.17.0
Package Manager: npm 10.8.2
OS: win32 arm64

Angular: 18.2.13
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1802.12
@angular-devkit/build-angular   18.2.12
@angular-devkit/core            18.2.12
@angular-devkit/schematics      18.2.12
@angular/cli                    18.2.12
@schematics/angular             18.2.12
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.5.4
zone.js                         0.14.10

Here is the warning
▲ [WARNING] Unable to initialize JavaScript cache storage. [plugin angular-compiler]

  No native build was found for platform=win32 arch=arm64 runtime=node abi=115 uv=1 armv=8 libc=glibc node=20.17.0
  This will not affect the build output content but may result in slower builds.

If I ignore this warning and run the application in browser, I see a strange behavior.
When i go back and forth between 2 routes (component A & component B), I see that the css files are download from the server every time I visit the route, as a result for a split second (until the css is downloaded from the server) I see that loaded html is distorted due to missing css. Not sure if this behavior is related to the warning.

EDITED Date: 12/30/2024 8:12 PM CST
Based on the suggestion by Matthieu Riegler, I have updated my config to below, but still getting the same error.
Angular CLI: 19.0.6
Node: 22.12.0
Package Manager: npm 10.9.0
OS: win32 arm64

Angular: 19.0.5
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1900.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular   19.0.6
@angular-devkit/core            19.0.6
@angular-devkit/schematics      19.0.6
@angular/cdk                    19.0.4
@angular/cli                    19.0.6
@angular/material               19.0.4
@schematics/angular             19.0.6
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.6.3
zone.js                         0.15.0


have you tried deleting package-lock.json, node_modules and .angular, then install and try running the build

no luck. still same issue

lmdb, a dependency of the Angular CLI, does not support your platform (a Windows ARM computer).
See this issue.
The work-around for this has landed on v19 only so you'll have to update your project to v19.

this is my current config
